# error Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 25;

Tags: java, spring, email, smtp

I am using spring-boot for web application and trying to log in using email. But I get this error

```
2020-11-13 00:31:05.943 ERROR 23492 --- [o-auto-1-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; message exceptions (1) are:
Failed message 1: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target] with root cause

sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

and my application properties code:

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.username=test@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=test123
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.port=465
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback=false
support.email=test@gmail.com
```

Tryed everything i have enabled less secure apps on gmail and still cant make it to work.

Comment: From the error info, you should define self class that extends SSLSocketFactory to import ssl cert file. Do you have ssl file?

Comment: i fixed it by disabling antivirus